# What is the difference between "Martin ~]#" and "sh-4.2#"

Tags: centos, gnu-screen, prompt

I use webmin for administrate my dedicated server (Centos 7 64 bits) and from there I create cron jobs, I am executing an .sh script as root which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash


screen -dmS aud
screen -S aud -X stuff "node /home/AuditTrail-Web/app.js
"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

Cron job execute that script on startup and when I join to that screen using:

```
screen -r aud
```

I get something similar to this(maybe named prompt?):

```
sh-4.2#
```

Which does not allow me **sometimes** to execute some commands like **fuser** and some other like **node /home/AuditTrail-Web/app.js**

But if I create the screen manually I get:

```
[root@Martin ~]#
```

And that allows me to execute everything.

What is the problem with **sh-4.2#** and why it is present in that form?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

You're defining something in either .bashrc or .bash_profile that you're relying on, especially for the node stuff.

Cron doesn't source/honor either .bashrc or .bash_profile, so those things don't get set when you start the screen.

At least that's my first guess.

Comment: Is not node, it allways happened me with any script making screens from the cron job, I really do not know why.

Comment: When the cron job execute on startup that bash script I get:

`sh-4.2# node /home/AuditTrail-Web/app.js
sh: node: no se encontrÃ³ la orden
sh-4.2#
sh-4.2# 
`